# Computing partial derivative of a matrix-valued function.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Suppose I had a function **y** = **Xw** + b**1** where X is an N by D matrix and W is a D-dimensional vector and 1 is a D-dimensional vector of 1's.

Now I define another function $\xi = \frac{1}{2N}|| $**y** $ - $ **t**$||^2$

Note that is a vector of scalars.

If I want to take the partial derivative $\frac{\partial\xi}{\partial \textbf{y}}$, I am a bit confused as to how to work this out.

Would I be computing the gradient?

$\frac{\partial\xi}{\partial \textbf{y}} = (\frac{\partial\xi}{\partial y_1}, ..., \frac{\partial\xi}{\partial y_n})$

But then computing an arbitrary i'th partial in the above gradient is:

$\frac{\partial\xi}{\partial y_i} = \frac{\partial\xi}{\partial y_i}(\frac{1}{2N}\sum_{j=1}^N(y_j - t_j)^2) = \frac{1}{N}(y_j - t_j) \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}(\textbf{Xw} + b\textbf{1}) $

which is where I get stuck.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, how do I apply the chain rule going forward?

Comment: $\frac{\partial\xi}{\partial y_i}$ is simply $\frac 1 N (y_i-t_i)$. There's no need to bring any more derivatives into it unless you really want the derivative with respect to something else like the components of $\mathbf X$ or $\mathbf w$.

Comment: @dfan Exactly. I think that's what he is asking for, otherwise the while definition of $y(x}$ is totally unuseful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\begin{align}\frac{1}{2N}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}||y-t||^2=\\
=\frac{1}{2N}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-t_i)^2=\\
\frac{1}{N}(y_i-t_i)
\end{align}$

Comment: You still need to take the derivative with respect to $y_i$.

Comment: That was done in the transformation from the second to the third line.

Comment: Is the derivative of (Xw+b1) with respect to Y_i equal to 1 for all i? I thought we would need to apply the chain rule again.

Comment: What makes you think you need the derivative of $(\mathbf X \mathbf w + b \mathbf 1)$ with respect to $y_i$ at all? If you're computing the partial derivative of $\xi$ with respect to $y_i$, it's completely irrelevant how $y_i$ was calculated.

Comment: I don't know. I guess I'm still confused, because I treated $y_i$ as a function of $X$, so I thought I had to differentiate by chain rule.

Comment: You would use the chain rule if you were trying to find the derivative of $\xi$ with respect to $\mathbf X$, in which case $\mathbf y$ would be a step along the way. But if you're just trying to find the derivative with respect to $y_i$, you can just stop there.

Comment: Hmm. Makes sense. What if I were to take the derivative with respect to X? What would the solution look like then?

Answer (score 1):

As gabriele cassese's answer indicated, if you are taking the derivative of $\xi$ with respect to $y_i$, you don't have to worry about where the $y_i$s came from at all. This answer is about how to find the derivative of $\xi$ with respect to $x_{ij}$, since you indicated an interest in that in a comment.

I find it easiest to approach these sorts of problems if I do everything with scalars and convert back to vectors and matrices later if necessary. So let's rewrite your original function for $y$, doing the matrix multiplication by hand:
$$y_i = \sum_j x_{ij}w_j + b_i$$
We also have
$$\xi = \frac1{2N}\sum_k(y_k-t_k)^2$$
(I have changed the index to $k$ for clarity in the following step.)

Now we can use the chain rule:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\xi}{\partial x_{ij}} &= \sum_k \frac{\partial \xi}{\partial y_k}\frac{\partial y_k}{\partial x_{ij}} \\
 &= \sum_k(y_k-t_k)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{ij}}\left(\sum_\ell x_{k\ell}w_\ell+b_k\right) \\
&= \sum_k(y_k-t_k)w_j\delta_{ik} \\
&= (y_i-t_i)w_j.
\end{align}
The third line works because the only way for $x_{ij}$ to have an effect on $y_k$ is if $i=k$ and $j=\ell$. (If you haven't encountered the Kronecker delta $\delta_{ik}$ before, it is equal to $1$ if $i=k$ and $0$ otherwise.)

You could now substitute the definition of $y_i$ back into that final equation (but be careful with your indices), if you wanted your final answer in terms of $\mathbf X$ and $b$.

Comment: Yep. That is consistent with what I got. Thanks a lot! :)